# How to use React PropTypes properly in a functional component which uses hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-proptypes

I am trying to use PropTypes in a functional React Component but I am getting `Hooks can only be called inside the body of a function component.` after adding the PropTypes.

I took a look at the PropType documentation and found the following

```
const myPropTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  age: PropTypes.number,
  // ... define your prop validations
};

const props = {
  name: 'hello', // is valid
  age: 'world', // not valid
};

// Let's say your component is called 'MyComponent'

// Works with standalone PropTypes
PropTypes.checkPropTypes(myPropTypes, props, 'age', 'MyComponent');
// This will warn as follows:
// Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `age` of type `string` supplied to
// `MyComponent`, expected `number`.
```

I can imagine using this in a functional component. But is this the only way, or is there a better way?

My Code looks like this right now:

```js
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const { title } = props;
  const [showTitle, setShowTitle] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={()=>setShowTitle(!showTitle)}>toggle title</button>
      {showTitle && <h1>{title}</h1>}
    </div>
  );

MyComponent.propType = {
  title: PropTypes.string
}

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  title: 'hello'
}
```

Comment: the code looks all good to me and it should produce any errors, please create a verifiable example on codesandbox or something.

Comment: The code here works correctly https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-fire-m0o0g

Comment: Alright, thanks for your support guys! It came beacuse I used the wrong react-dom version. Should have checked that straight away. I was using react-dom@16.2.0.